# NMI gateway in OMNIPAY

Tags: payment-gateway, omnipay, civicrm, civicrm-extension, nmi-payments

Trying to add NMI integration to my CiviCRM using OMNIPAY.

I added the GIT repository (tried https://github.com/mfauveau/omnipay-nmi and https://github.com/nerdmedia/omnipay-nmi) and added the required line that is listed in the readme.

I also created an MGD.PHP file for it and added it to the metadata folder (though not sure I did it correctly).

When uploading the whole folder to my CiviCRM extensions and installing the extension, I'm getting omnipay - NMI as a payment processor in CiviCRM but when trying to do a contribution I'm getting an error "class '\Omnipay\NMI\DirectPostGateway' not found"

Not sure if I'm missing something or doing something wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe more answers at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think it's more of an omnipay question, gotta figure out how to add it to omnipay properly. Though I'll try to post there too I guess.